# What determines a chance shot?

Tags: mario-tennis-open

Chance shots appear as a glowing circle on the court. They are not random, as one can deny an opponent from ever seeing a chance shot circle in an entire match. They are typically different colors like orange or purple.

What determines if these show up?

Comment: Don't know enough for an answer, but in previous games smash chances were produced by certain shots against certain other shots(such as using a topspin on an incoming slice), while lunges also always produced smash chances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weak returns give your opponent a chance shot.  The spin / lob of the weak return is what determines the type of chance shot.

A weak return is one that is poorly timed or not an accurate hit.